# Create an object iterating over other

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript

I want to remove the null key of and object and I try to do it in this way

```
object = {
    item1: null,
    item2: 'hi',
    item3: null,
    item4: 'bye',
    item5: null
  };

let params = {};
for (let param in this.object) {
  if (this.object[param])
    params.param = this.object[param];
}

console.log(params);
```

I expect: params = {
        item2: 'hi',
        item4: 'bye',
      }

but I have: params = {
        param: 'bye',
      }

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: `params.param = this.object[param];` - you're overwriting the same key each time. Change it to `params[param] = this.object[param]`

Comment: why downvoting this?

Comment: Thats what I asking my self... why downvoting :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `param` key everytime on your `params` object, try this instead:

```
params[param] = this.object[param]
```

so your loop will look like:

```
let params = {};
for (let param in this.object) {
  if (this.object[param]) param[param] = this.object[param];
}
```